# Dynamically setting PreserveOnRefresh for Route in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin you can place the PreserveOnRefresh annotation on a route target.

I wonder if there is a way to enable this dynamically since you can't change annotations during runtime.

Back in vaadin 8 we used multiple UI's for this and enabled them based on Spring profiles

Answer (score 1):

At least at the moment, there doesn't seem to be a mechanism for that; there is a method `boolean isPreserveOnRefreshTarget` in `AbstractNavigationStateRenderer` that returns `true` if the annotation is present in the route target type or its parent layouts. I don't see a convenient way of overriding that; I recommend opening a ticket in https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues

Comment: Yeah i already saw that. Also in WebComponentUI its enabled by checking if the annotation is present. So i guess you're right i need to open a ticket. Thank you anyways